# pip missing dependencies in setup.py

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to use pip to get an environment set up, and running pip install -e ./ from the root directory of my project isn't picking everything up. I've got a setup.py file with a requires section that looks like so:

```
requires = [
'phonenumbers',
'inflect',
'repoze.sendmail==4.1',
'pyramid',
'pyramid_chameleon',
'pyramid_debugtoolbar',
'pyramid_mailer',
'pyramid_tm',
'transaction',
'zope.sqlalchemy',
'waitress',
'pyramid_beaker',
'cryptacular',
'pycrypto',
'webtest',
'alembic',
'psycopg2',
'python-dateutil',
'sqlalchemy-utils',
'cryptacular',
'arrow',
'jsonpickle',
'sqlalchemy',
'pyramid_storage',
'boto',
'requests'
]
```

When the command is run, some libraries, such as boto, won't be installed. Does anyone know why these packages would be missed?

Edit: Here's the call to setup in setup.py, with some irrelevent bits ommited:

```
dependency_links = [
'git+https://github.com/benthor/inflect.py#egg=inflect',
]
setup(
  classifiers=[
    "Programming Language :: Python",
    "Framework :: Pyramid",
    "Topic :: Internet :: WWW/HTTP",
    "Topic :: Internet :: WWW/HTTP :: WSGI :: Application",
    ],
  author='',
  author_email='',
  url='',
  keywords='web wsgi bfg pylons pyramid',
  packages=find_packages(),
  include_package_data=True,
  zip_safe=False,
  test_suite='test',
  install_requires=requires,
  dependency_links=dependency_links
  )
```

Comment: `dependency_links` is potentially relevant?

Comment: I updated the OP to include it.

Answer (score 2):

The `requires` argument to `setup()` doesn't actually do anything, and for all intents and purposes should be considered deprecated and useless.

Use [`install_requires`](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#new-and-changed-setup-keywords) instead.

Comment: (Unless of course you are passing that list to `install_requires`, but it wasn't clear from your post.)

Comment: I do pass that list to install_requires. Sorry about that, I'll update my post.